# How to improve visibility of the current tab in Delphi IDE?

Tags: delphi

I have a big problem while using Delphi XE under Windows 7.
The color of the tab for the active PAS file (Delphi IDE editor) is almost identical with the color of the inactive tabs. So you cannot really tell which is the active tab. Any of you have the same problem? How to fix this?

Comment: I think it's not possible - as far as I know, it's a custom control and is custom-drawn. (I remember seeing a plugin that used VCL themes to theme the IDE some time ago, and it couldn't change how the tabs rendered.)

Comment: So, this is indeed a problems for others too. Not only for me.... I thought I am too picky.

Comment: Maybe hacking the Win 7 theme?

Comment: I don't personally have trouble seeing the active tab :)  But I would like to make the IDE look nicer, and using VCL themes seems the logical technique. So I was disappointed when I found not all parts of the IDE respect themes.

Comment: I myself could solve this a little by adjusting brightness and contrast of my screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, there is not plugin (yet) to set custom colors for the IDE tabs (`TIDEGradientTabSet`) , but you can accomplish this task creating a OTA (open tools API) plugin to access the  tabs and change the colors. The OTA doesn't expose a interface to manipulate this component directly but you can use the `RTTI` to access this class and the Color related properties. You can see a dump of this component [`here`](http://delphi-ide-theme-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/delphi-ide-theme-editor/IDE%20PlugIn/Galileo/TIDEGradientTabSet.pas) (part of the [DITE](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-ide-theme-editor/) project), which was made using RTTI.